# Determine SGX enclaves running on same system

Tags: sgx

I have two applications A1 and A2, both creating there own enclave E1 and E2.
A third application A3 is connected to A1 and A2. Is it possible for A3 to determine if the two enclaves E1 and E2 are actually running on the same system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Signing Identity provided by an authority, which signs the enclave prior to distribution. This value is called MRSIGNER and will be the same for all enclaves signed with the same authority. So in the same development firm all enclaves should have same MRSIGNER value, if they are signed with same Signing Identity.

This MRSIGNER values from two different enclaves in a development environment can be used to check whether two enclaves belongs to the same environment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with Surenthar's answer. If E1 and E2 are signed by the same Signing Identity MRSIGNER will always be the same for E1 and E2. Because MRSIGNER is a hash of that identity.

If A3 is also execute on the same platform it can simply spawn an enclave E3 and use local attestation which will only succeed for enclaves on the same platform.

If you have control over E1 and E2 then they could use local attestation to make sure both run on the same platform. Then A3 would have to use remote attestation to make sure it can trust E1's (or E2's) statement.

Comment: A3 has to perform remote attestation as mentioned above, or A3 needs to create its own enclave E3 and individually perform local attestation with E1 and E2. Note that local attestation can be entirely spoofed easily by something like a hypervisor. The only way to tell you are running on real hardware is using remote attestation.

Comment: Take the comment about local attestation spoofing back. VMM's cannot trap ENCLU instructions, so local attestation reports guarantee that you are running on SGX hardware.